# How I can send an email to 2 or more email on send mail layout laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('You have new follower')
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->line('Welcome to my application')
                ->line('Thank you');
}
```

When run, it was only sent to one email, the email when input data.

How do if I want to send an email to 2 or more email?

I read on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications, but I did not find it

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#introduction) are used to notify single model (in most cases it's user model) via various channels, and one of them is `mail`. If you want to send email to multiple people, you might consider using [Laravel's mailing functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#sending-mail).

However, since notifications (via email) are also using Laravel's mailing functions, you can simply use this, although I wouldn't recommend it:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('You have new follower')
                ->cc('other.recipient@mail.com') // I've added this
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->line('Welcome to my application')
                ->line('Thank you');
}
```

edit: Don't know why it doesn't work for you, the method `cc()` exists in `MailMessage` class, as shown in this image:

[image: The cc method exists]

Comment: It's not working. There exist error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::cc()`

Comment: Hm, very strange as [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.html#method_cc) say the method exists. I will have to check this myself when I'm back at my dev machine.

Comment: I have checked MailMessage class and that method exists. Can you check your copy of MailMessage class? Maybe try `composer update`? :)